# Add remaining value to next rows in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table, as below and its contains customer electricity volume for the period as.Available data like

```
     OwnerID    StartDate   EndDate     Volume
        1       2019-01-01  2019-01-15  10.40
        1       2019-01-16  2019-01-31  5.80
        1       2019-02-01  2019-02-10  7.90
        1       2019-02-11  2019-02-28  8.50
        2       2019-03-01  2019-03-04  10.50
```

And another table having their existing remaining volume. Both table are connected with Column OwnerID

```
OwnerID   ExistingVolume
1         0.90
2         0.60
```

Now add (apply) the ExistingVolume with current Volume (first table) as 
    Calculate the new volume as whole numer and remaining decimal value add to next period to the customer.

```
So expected result set should like, 

    OwnerId StartDate   EndDate     CalulatedVolume RemainingExistingVolume 
    1       2019-01-01  2019-01-15  11              0.30
    1       2019-01-16  2019-01-31  6               0.10
    1       2019-02-01  2019-02-10  8               0.00
    1       2019-02-11  2019-02-28  8               0.50
    2       2019-03-01  2019-03-04  11              0.10
```

Don't round off the CalulatedVolume. Just get the whole when add the table1.Volume + table2.ExistingVolume. 
And Remaining decimal value (from 1st row) should be applied the next row value table1.Volume
Could you someone suggest how to achieve this is in SQL query?

Comment: `8.5` when rounded -- by the rules of normal rounding -- goes to 9 not 8.

Comment: Please see my updated query and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to accumulative the "error" from rounding and apply that against the value in the second table.

You can use a cumulative sum for this purpose -- along with some arithmetic:

```
select t1.ownerid, t1.startdate, t1.enddate,
       round(t1.volume, 0) as calculatedvolume,
       ( sum( t1.volume - round(t1.volume, 0) ) over (partition by t1.ownerid order by t1.startdate) +
         t2.existingvolume
       ) as remainingexisting
from table1 t1 left join
     table2 t2
     on t1.ownerid = t2.ownerid;
```

You have a non-standard definition of rounding.  This can be implemented as `ceil(x - 0.5)`.  With this definition, the code is:

```
select t1.ownerid, t1.startdate, t1.enddate,
       ceiling(t1.volume - 0.5) as calculatedvolume,
       ( sum( t1.volume - ceiling(t1.volume - 0.5) ) over (partition by t1.ownerid order by t1.startdate) +
         t2.existingvolume
       ) as remainingexisting
from table1 t1 left join
     table2 t2
     on t1.ownerid = t2.ownerid;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=e67ac49997f4ebee6bc57edc0c0eb805) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: it might be best to use floor() or {fn truncate} because .5 is rounded down and not up: select floor(8.5), {fn TRUNCATE( 8.5, 0 )}, round(8.5, 0); --- or celing(-.5) :)