# add current row value with previous row calculated value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table with table as below

```
OwnerId StartDate      EndDate      Volume
1         2020-01-01    2020-01-01  10.80
1         2020-01-02    2020-01-02  5.60
1         2020-01-03    2020-01-03  7.90
1         2020-01-04    2020-01-04  8.50
```

Another table having their previous value.

```
OwnerId PreviousVolume
1        0.70
```

1) The previous volume should **ADD** with my first table **first row**. And then get whole number part and decimal part value.

2) The decimal part add with first table **second row** and then get whole number and decimal part and vice-versa.

```
ownerid startdate   enddate     Volume    Calculatedvolume  remainingexisting
1      2020-01-01   2020-01-01    10.80         11                   0.50
1      2020-01-02   2020-01-02    5.60           6                   0.10
1      2020-01-03   2020-01-03    7.90           8                   0.00
1      2020-01-04   2020-01-04    8.50           8                   0.50
```

Could you please anyone help?

Comment: In your data there is a mistake ? In the result data that you expect to get there is a volume 5,60. It should be 5,80 ?

Comment: 5.60+ 0.50 = 6.10

Comment: But in the original data(first table) you have (10.80; 5.80; 7.90; 8.50)

Comment: How is this different from  your previous question?  (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59591022/add-remaining-value-to-next-rows-in-sql-server and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59591839/add-first-row-decimal-value-to-next-rows-in-sql-server).  You should also accept answers on those questions or at least explain why you are not accepting them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, the next statement may help to get your expected results:

Tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1 (
    OwnerId int, 
    StartDate date,      
    EndDate date,      
    Volume numeric(10, 2)
)
INSERT INTO Table1 
   (OwnerId, StartDate, EndDate, Volume)
VALUES
    (1, '20200101', '20200101', 10.80),
    (1, '20200102', '20200102', 5.60),
    (1, '20200103', '20200103', 7.90),
    (1, '20200104', '20200104', 8.50)
CREATE TABLE Table2 (
    OwnerId int,
    PreviousVolume numeric(10, 2)
)
INSERT INTO Table2 
    (OwnerId, PreviousVolume)
VALUES
    (1, 0.70)
```

Statement:

```
;WITH DataCte AS (
    SELECT OwnerId, NULL AS StartDate, NULL AS EndDate, PreviousVolume AS Volume
    FROM Table2
    UNION ALL
    SELECT OwnerId, StartDate, EndDate, Volume
    FROM Table1
), CalculationCTE AS (
    SELECT 
        OwnerId, StartDate, EndDate, Volume,
        SUM(Volume) OVER (PARTITION BY OwnerId ORDER BY StartDate) AS Total,
        CONVERT(numeric(10, 2), FLOOR(SUM(Volume) OVER (PARTITION BY OwnerId ORDER BY StartDate))) AS TotalFloor
    FROM DataCTE
)
SELECT
    OwnerId, StartDate, EndDate,
    FLOOR(Total - LAG(TotalFloor) OVER (PARTITION BY OwnerID ORDER BY StartDate)) AS CalculatedVolume,
    Total - TotalFloor AS RemainingExisting
FROM CalculationCTE
```

Result:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------
OwnerId StartDate   EndDate     CalculatedVolume    RemainingExisting
---------------------------------------------------------------------
1       NULL        NULL        NULL                0.70 
1       2020-01-01  2020-01-01  11                  0.50
1       2020-01-02  2020-01-02  6                   0.10
1       2020-01-03  2020-01-03  8                   0.00
1       2020-01-04  2020-01-04  8                   0.50
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this kind of query might work for your problem but also I have another idea with LEAD() (or LAG()?) function which I will edit my answer and add it if this didnt work:

```
DECLARE @count = 1;

SELECT TOP 1 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY T1.OwnerId ORDER BY T1.startdate,T1.enddate) R#
    ,T1.OwnerId 
    ,T1.StartDate      
    ,T1.EndDate      
    ,T1.Volume
    ,FLOOR(T1.Volumn+T2.PreviousVolum) AS Calculatedvolume  
    ,(T1.Volumn+T2.PreviousVolum)%1 AS remainingexisting 
INTO #tmp
FROM T1 
INNER JOIN T2 ON T1.OwnerId = T2.OwnerId
ORDER BY T1.startdate,T1.enddate;

WHILE @count > (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM T1) 
BEGIN 

    INSERT INTO #tmp
    SELECT 
         @count+1
        ,T1.OwnerId 
        ,T1.StartDate      
        ,T1.EndDate      
        ,T1.Volume
        ,FLOOR(T1.Volumn+T2.Calculatedvolume) AS Calculatedvolume  
        ,(T1.Volumn+T2.Calculatedvolume)%1 AS remainingexisting 
    FROM T1 
    INNER JOIN #tmp T2 ON T1.OwnerId = T2.OwnerId AND T2.R# = @count
    WHERE ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY T1.startdate,T1.enddate) = @count+1;

    SET @count += 1;

END
```

Comment: Can we achieve without WHILE loop?

Comment: Yes I think so. the fact is that you should calculate first row once and then calculate other rows with their previous rows in the next step. @KannanMuthiah

Comment: so it becomes like this: step1- caculate first rows for each ownerId in one query. step2- calculate other rows